# Pending promises even though awaiting Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm having difficulty understanding why I still have pending promises after awaiting [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

In the example below, I'm creating an array of promises by calling an async function on each element of an array, using `.map()`.

Now, why is the promise still showing as pending? The way I (mis)understand it right now:

- `then()` fires once the promise from `storeData()` resolves
- `storeData()`resolves once `newDataArray` is returned
- `newDataArray` is returned once all promises inside the `promisesArray` are resolved or once the first one rejects.

```
storeData(OldDataArray).then(values => console.log(values))
// console shows:
// { id: 1, data: Promise { <pending> } },
// { id: 2, data: Promise { <pending> } }
```

```
const storeData = async (OldDataArray) => {
  try {
      const promisesArray = OldDataArray.map((item) => {
      let newData = downloadMoreDetails(item.id, item.group); //async function, see below
      return {
        id: item.id,
        data: newData,
      };
    });
    const newDataArray = await Promise.all(promisesArray);  // <-- I'm awaiting all promises to complete before assigning to newDataArray
    return newDataArray;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

```
const downloadMoreDetails = async (id, group) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `example.com/id/group.xml`
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
  }

  const str = await response.text();
  const json = convert.xml2json(str, {
    compact: true,
    spaces: 2,
  });
  return json;
};
```

Comment: `promisesArray` isn't an array of promises, thats why awaiting it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks! If async functions always return a promise and I'm calling an async function inside map, why is the result of map not an array of promises?

Comment: `If async functions always return a promise and I'm calling an async function inside map` Because __being__ an async function and __calling__ an async function are different things. Your function passed to `map` isn't async.

Comment: `newData` is a promise, but you're awaiting an array of `{id: item.id,  data: newData }`.  `Promise.all()` doesn't look inside those objects to find the promise and wait for that promise.  It just sees an array of plain objects which means it has nothing to do.

Comment: Add promises to your array, not objects... `OldDataArray.map(({ id, group }) => downloadMoreDetails(id, group).then(data => ({ id, data })))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newData` is a promise, but you're not awaiting the promise.  Instead, you're awaiting an array of objects `{id: item.id,  data: newData }` that has the promise inside it.  `Promise.all()` doesn't look inside those objects to find the promise and wait for that promise.  It just sees an array of plain objects which means it has nothing to do.  You can fix that by doing this:

```
const storeData = async (OldDataArray) => {
  try {
    const promisesArray = OldDataArray.map(async (item) => {
        let newData = await downloadMoreDetails(item.id, item.group); //async function, see below
        return {
          id: item.id,
          data: newData,
        };
    });
    return Promise.all(promisesArray);
  } catch (error) {
    // log and rethrow error so the caller gets the rejection
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

This changes the `.map()` callback to be `async`.  That does two beneficial things.  First, it means the resulting array from `.map()` will be an array of promises since the `async` callback always returns a promise.  And, second, it allows you to use `await` inside the callback so you can populate your returned object with the actual data, not with a promise.

Then, the `return` from inside the `async` callback will cause that value to become the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function is returning.

---

Note, you could have also done it without adding the `async/await` like this:

```
const storeData = (OldDataArray) => {
    const promisesArray = OldDataArray.map((item) => {
       return downloadMoreDetails(item.id, item.group).then(newData => {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            data: newData,
          };
       });
    });
    return Promise.all(promisesArray).catch(error => {
      // log and rethrow error so the caller gets the rejection
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    });
};
```

In this version, you directly return a promise from the `.map()` callback and you make sure that promise resolves to your data object.

Comment: This makes sense. So in plain English, by mapping over the array with an async function, each item in the resulting array will be a promise (that's good, because then we can await that array with `Promise.all`). Then, each promise inside the array resolves/rejects depending on what `downloadMoreDetails` returns. I think I have it..

Comment: @SPi - See the additional solution I added that does not use `async/await` so you can see how you would do it that way too.

Comment: Very nice explanation (Y)